# How Do You Use New Packages Installed Via GitHub?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the MITxGraders library from https://github.com/mitodl/mitx-grading-library.

I have clones it, run pip install -r requirements3.txt in the Command Line like they told me to, run Pytest to see that it is working, and now I have no idea how to use it.

I tried to pip install the library in Jupyter Notebook and I tried to import it in the same notebook, and in both cases the code said the module didn't exist. I tried to import the file location of **"C:\Users\nolan\Desktopmitx-grading-library"**, and it spit back a Syntax Error of

```
"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"
```

I'm really annoyed that my Data Science bootcamp never bothered teaching me how this works, but I'm really hoping someone on here can help me out.

Comment: where is the cloned repo in relation to the files you are using?  I don't think those install instructions get it installed as a proper module only it's dependencies which is odd.

Comment: 'I tried to import the file location of "C:\Users\nolan\Desktopmitx-grading-library"' Importing a file path is not a meaningful operation. Please show the *entire* traceback as well as the rough code triggering the error. See the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: If you installed with pip you should just import the module by its name like `import xgraders` or whatever the library is actually called.

Comment: you can do `help('modules')` in the prompt to see a list of all available modules if you don't know that actual module name.

Comment: Tadhg,  it's in a different folder in the Desktop. Should it be in the same folder?

MisterMiyagi, all of the coding that has worked was done in the Command Line. I just went into the folder and Pip Installed a file in it. Nothing I've done or coded since then has done anything.

Jonatan, importing it does nothing, and it doesn't exist in help('modules').

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you are using a normal string as a path. You can use one of the following solutions to fix your problem.

a) Just put r before your normal string it converts normal string to raw string:

```
r"C:\Users\nolan\Desktopmitx-grading-library"
```

b)

```
"C:/Users/nolan/Desktopmitx-grading-library"
```

c)

```
"C:\\Users\\nolan\\Desktopmitx-grading-library"
```

Comment: All 3 said invalid syntax.